# boost compilation generates libboost_python instead of boost_python

Tags: c++, python-3.x, boost, boost-python

I am trying to use boost/python.

After compiling python, boost_1_72_0\stage\lib\libboost_python38-vc142-mt-x64-1_72.lib is generated.

However, visual studio wants boost_python38-vc142-mt-x64-1_72.lib instead.

renaming the file seems to work, but what went wrong here?

Comment: I can't recall exactly, but the `libxxx` ones I think are static library builds and without the DLL version (the `.lib` being the import library for the DLL). I believe some macro's you can define before including boost like `BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK ` control which it wants to use, as well as flags when building boost itself. Also looks like can be configured by `boost/config/user.hpp`

Comment: compiling boost using b2 runtime-link=static generates the required boost_python38-vc142-mt-x64-1_72.lib however... I would prefer to use the static libraries, is there a way to specify use of the static libraries? When using other parts of boost, the static libraries work without changing anything

Comment: I think it is `link=static`. `runtime-link` is if to use the static or shared C/C++ runtimes. Assuming Boost.Python itself is not specifically special somehow, they might have thought everyone would want DLL version+DLL Python due to something to do with `import` of Python native modules (which are themselves DLL's on Windows). Also try putting `BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB ` in your own project, it should either force it or at least give a clear "not supported" type error.

Comment: yeah link=static is what I used, runtime-link is a typo